# How to scan for and detect bio-energy? Does the technology exist?

Tags: sensor

Similar to how Star Trek space craft could scan a planet for life, I'm wondering if there is a way to scan a given area and detect all the living organisms inside it. For example, being able to scan a forest to find a missing person. Does anyone know if something like this exists yet?

Comment: Go get a tricorder, or maybe a Jedi knight to sense the life forces.

Comment: you have to define what level of "life" you want/need to detect. trying to detect bacteria from orbit is a whole nother project from trying to determine if there are any creatures above 100lbs roaming around. optical tracking is probably the most plausable that i know of.  I believe some spy satalites can track a sparrow in flight and can use thermal detection. using a program it can filter out all movement that would be expected when wind blows so that tubleweed objects are removed but animals that do not follow the winds path are marked.

Answer (score 7):

Part of this is philosophical. What does "life" mean?

That's relevant because when we talk about "scanning for" something, it is implied that the quantity you are detecting is intrinsic to the target and exclusively so (the concept of sensor selectivity).

If you permit me to make some gross assumptions about your problem and limit it to detecting humans in a forest, several technologies exist.

- Thermal: The human body gives off heat (that's why your internal temperature is ~98.6F, while you are most comfortable at ~72F external temperature). Various technologies exist to visualize this difference. Forward-Looking InfraRed (FLIR) is broad class of these systems. You can see it in action [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yz7B2e8_XOE).
- Electromagnetic: The RF impedance of the human body (being largely composed of an electrolytic solution -- salt water) is detectable from the scattering effect it has on radio (RADAR) waves. A technique using a repositioned antenna known as Synthetic Aperture RADAR (SAR) is the most frequently employed class of these systems for ground-scanning applications. An example is [here](http://www.es.northropgrumman.com/solutions/starlite/).
- Acoustic: Passive systems use an array of microphones (distributed or otherwise) to localize the source of sounds. Humans make noise. Ergo, we can localize those sounds. Active systems use sound waves to map the geometry of the reflecting surfaces (like Bats). However, humans are not uniquely selective in this modality. A human looks like a tree-stump (more or less) to active acoustics.
- Active Structured: Humans have hands and can carry stuff... like a rescue beacon! =) If you are looking for a target that *wants to be found*, you can equip the target with a device that emits either a signal you can recognize (solves the selectivity problem) and localize, or, better, contains its position explicitly (like a GPS transponder).

Comment: +1 for GPS transponders, even for people *not* wanting to be found, such as leg bracelets for prisoners on parole in various movies and TV serials!

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Also for people not wanting to be found but inadvertently broadcasting signals, as in cell phone tracking (or on a more macro scale, the type of signal the SETI project is looking for).

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing we have are thermal imaging cameras that detect heat.  Warm blooded animals and humans will show up.  But there are many ways to hide from these. It is a long way from StarTrek.

One problem is bio-energy.  It doesn't exist. It is a fictional thing used as a plot device in science fiction. There are some pseudo-scientific people who claim it exists, along with auras and quantum consciousness, but that is no more real than other science fiction.

Addition:

Electroreception, the process that the sharks use, is only useful to a range of about one body length and many animals are completely invisible to such methods. Further, electroreception is seen almost exclusively in aquatic animals because this electro-magnetic effect works much better in water than air. I didn't consider electroreception in my original answer because it would not work from a search and rescue helicopter or space ship.

Comment: Depends on how one defines bio-energy.  Surely the heat we radiate is energy.  Also, sharks can detect the electrical signals of their prey.  That minute electric field is akin to what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @TonyEnnis  I added stuff about electroreception in my answer.

Comment: I'll contest "no more real than other science fiction". A lot of science fiction is based on likely or at least highly plausible science. "Bio-energy" is no more real than other *fantasy* like hobbits and elves.